# Confusion on how SQL Offsets work?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, oracle, offset

I read that SQL Offset reads each time all rows and starts at the given Offset. That means higher Offsets will result in higher loading time. In the meantime, if the order is manipulated (e.g. deletion) there will be problems for the result set; therefore, you shouldn't use it.

Are there any reputable sources that verify that is correct?

Comment: did you google it?

Comment: yes that's right.  Try it out for yourself.  So say I have records 1-10 and and I display 1-5 then 6-10.  while viewing the the 1-5 subset someone goes in and deletes record 5.  If I refresh the page I see 1,2,3,4,6 now.  If I don't refresh and select the next page, the system returns the next only containing 7-10 since 6 will now be in the first offset 1,2,3,4,6 and 7,8,9,10.  Why is that wrong ? Do you want to see up to date information or static information?   Say if they deleted record 7.  Should I still see record 7 on the next page?

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page talks extensively about it I believe.

Comment: Yes using Offset will help you select from a particular range and it will display data from that point/range. When any operations performed like delete on the data which you had selected it will get disturbed next time you try.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Well, the behaviour after operations is ok. For the paging Problem, the mentioned Website is very helpful.